# jQuery UI Slider: Range with 3 handles, and configurable colors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like a jQuery UI slider that has five differently colored ranges defined by three handles. (So the first range would be handle 0 - handle 1, and the second range would be handle 1 to handle 2.) Is this possible through configuration, or must I hack it? If I have to modify the source, is there any guidelines for how to go about doing that?

**Update**: What I'm looking for in terms of ranges is:

| --- color 1 ----- handle1 --------- color 2 ------------- handle2 ------- color3 --------- handle3 -----color 4 ----|

(hopefully that makes sense.)

Comment: Maybe this? https://github.com/val-samonte/angular-multirange

Answer (score 17):

The range option defined in the jquery ui slider documentation does indeed limit the slider to  only 2 handles. You need to create several elements when the slider raises the 'slide' or 'change' event and set the position of these manually, this way you can create a slider with multiple handles and multiple ranges which you can apply custom css to. See fiddle for a working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/AV3G3/3/

Comment: This is awesome - thank you. I think there is a small bug where it should be position() and not offset() in the doUpdate() method. http://jsfiddle.net/AV3G3/60/ Otherwise the slider goes all crazy wide buried inside a real app

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a [range slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range) and pass in an array of 3 values to create 3 handles (according to the docs):

> The slider widget will create handle
>   elements with the class
>   'ui-slider-handle' on initialization.
>   You can specify custom handle elements
>   by creating and appending the elements
>   and adding the 'ui-slider-handle'
>   class before init. **It will only create
>   the number of handles needed to match
>   the length of value/values. For
>   example, if you specify 'values: [1,
>   5, 18]' and create one custom handle,
>   the plugin will create the other two.**

Comment: Right, but it says that if `range: true`, it will force there to only be two sliders.

Comment: Probably because it doesn't know what range you want. You can pull the positions of the handles down and use whatever logic you come up with to determine your ranges (e.g. Handle A to Handle B = Range 1; Handle B to Handle C = Range 2). It's restrictive, though. You might want to just use two range sliders instead and call it a day.

Comment: It's been a while since I played with the sliders, but I've done a lot with them in the past. I haven't ever wanted to select a range of colors, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist on jQuery UI, [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) can give ranges different classes and supports multiple handles - just as you ask. [This example](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-colored-connect) demonstrates how to color the ranges.

Comment: Worth a further look for this 'multirange' purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Modified with onclick reset,please find the complete code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Slider functionality</title>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <!-- Javascript -->
      <style>
      .slide {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    background: red;
}
.slide-back {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
}

      </style>
   </head>

   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
      <button class="button">submit</button>
      <p>
         <label for = "price">Price range:</label>
         <input type = "text" id = "price" 
            style = "border:0; color:#b9cd6d; font-weight:bold;">
      </p>
      <div id = "slider-3"></div>
   </body>
   <script>

    var doUpdate = function(event, ui) {
        $('#slider-3 .slide-back').remove();
        $($('#slider-3 a').get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
            var bg = '#fff';
            if(i == 1) {
                bg = 'red';
            } else if(i == 2) {
                bg = 'yellow';
            } else if(i == 3) {
                bg = 'green';
            } 

            $('#slider-3').append($('<div></div>').addClass('slide-back').width($(this).offset().left - 5).css('background', bg));

        });
    };
    $(".button").click(function(){
    $('#slider-3').slider({
        slide: doUpdate,
        change: doUpdate,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        values: [ 10, 30, 20],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( "#price" ).val( ui.values[ 2 ] );
               }
    });
    $( "#price" ).val( $( "#slider-3" ).slider( "values", 0 )
               );
    doUpdate();
       });
    $('#slider-3').slider({
        slide: doUpdate,
        change: doUpdate,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        values: [ 10, 30, 20],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( "#price" ).val( ui.values[ 2 ] );
               }
    });
    $( "#price" ).val( $( "#slider-3" ).slider( "values", 0 ) );
    doUpdate();


      </script>
</html>
```