# Editing jQuery UI Source

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery UI framework, but I'd like to modify the slider control to suit my needs. I only want to make changes in that one file. What is the best way to include those changes in my project? Currently I have it all wrapped up in `jquery-ui-1.8.8.custom.min.js`.

Options include:

1. Edit the minified source directly. Seems like a huge pain.
2. Download all the source files, put them in my `/js` directory, and add `<script>` tags for each one. Ugh.
3. Try to make the changes from outside the framework, using my own script. I'm not sure this would work.
4. Somehow use the one file I modify + the rest of the framework in the single minified file?
5. Download the entire framework, modify the file I want, then compress it into a single file. (But is then debugging/testing will require `<script>` tags for all the source files, right?) (How do I minify the code?)

If I were to be including `<script>` tags for every source file, could I only use the ones I'm interested in, and their explicitly stated dependencies? Or is this asking for trouble? (**Update**: Looks like this works.)

Other ideas? Is (4) possible? What is the best approach here?

**Update**: I see that the minified file is of the form:

```
/***
 * UI Slider
 */
minifiedCode();
/***
 * UI Autocomplete
 */
minifiedCode();
/***
 * UI Spinner
 */
minifiedCode();
```

What if I comment out the Slider code, then include my own non-minified, altered Slider file? Can minified and non-minified code work together?

Comment: Edit the non-minified source to make your life easier. Minify your file when done.  What is the nature of the customization?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the effect specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731709/jquery-ui-slider-range-with-3-handles-and-configurable-colors

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the changes - if you are overriding a method, you can put it in a separate js file and load that file after you load jQuery - it will override the method functionality.

Comment: Can I really override it? It's wrapped in: `(function( $, undefined ){ /* ... */ }(jQuery));`. Doesn't that put the enveloped code in its own scope?

Comment: I haven't seen source code for that plugin. You might or might not be able to override it. If it's not a named function, then I guess not. Can you post a piece of code you want to override?

Comment: Changes will probably have to be made in multiple places in https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.slider.js

Comment: Well, then I guess your best option is to make changes to that file and the load it after you load jQuery UI - it will override the default slider plugin, I think.